# Only exposing certain auth routes in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.2 authentication is made dead simple and one of the ways it makes authentication simpler is by adding all routes necessary for authentication through one method, this method is `Route::auth()`.

Which is great, but what is the best way of only exposing the ones necessary for login and logout actions and not the registration ones, because I want to have one master login, which can make other accounts to admin the website. But I don't want 'users' in the normal sense.

Answer (score 5):

Method 1.

Add routes in `web.php` file.
For example when your app need only login and logout routes

```
Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
```

Method 2 - There is a better way. 
Just use the `Auth::routes()` method and add additional parameters.
Same example - App needs just login and logout routes

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false, 'reset' => false])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add to routes.php without registration route of course.

```
// Authentication Routes...
//Login Routes...
Route::get('login','AdminAuth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('login','AdminAuth\AuthController@login');
Route::get('logout','AdminAuth\AuthController@logout');


// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');


// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset/{token?}','Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you run have the `Route::auth()` method in your `routes.php` and run the `php artisan route:list` command you can see which routes it defines.

In this case they're:

```
+--------+----------+-------------------------+------+----------------------     -------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                     | Name | Action                                                           | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                       |      | Closure                                                         | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                    |      | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                       | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                   |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm          | web,guest  |
|        | POST     | login                   |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login                  | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD | logout                  |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@logout                 | web        |
|        | POST     | password/email          |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail | web,guest  |
|        | POST     | password/reset          |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@reset              | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token?} |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm      | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD | register                |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm   | web,guest  |
|        | POST     | register                |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register               | web,guest  |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

You can clearly see which are necessary in the URI colum; `login` (get), `login` (post) and `logout` (get).

Remove the `Route::auth()` method from `routes.php` and add the following:

```
Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
```

If you do want the already registered admins to be able to manually change their password you would also include those:

```
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
Route::get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
```

Don't forget the tools given to you :)